# how to proof (not necessarily in the official way) min with constraint

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

I know it's kind of question that the common answer is easy to see...
still looking for some more official way to formulate it.

$$ min_{y,x} y \ \   s.t. \    y \ge f(x)   =  min_x f(x)  \ | x,y\in \mathbb{R}, f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $$

any suggestions?

Comment: What does "official way" mean?

Comment: Do you really mean $\iff$? That should occur only between statements ...

Comment: What does the lhs of the inequality mean? Does it mean the smallest $y$ such that $y\ge f(x)$ for **some** $x$? And are you talking about the reals? (ie $x,y$ real and $f$ a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Rahul I mean full math proof

Answer (score 1):

You are given a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$, and form the set
$$A=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigm| y\geq f(x)\bigr\}=\bigcup_{x\in{\mathbb R}}\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm|y\geq f(x)\bigr\}\ .$$
It is then claimed that
$$\min\bigl\{y\bigm|(x,y)\in A\bigr\}=\min\bigl\{f(x)\bigm| x\in{\mathbb R}\bigr\}\ ,$$
whereby we tacitly assume that these minima exist. There is not much to prove: By definition of $A$ 
we can write
$$\min\bigl\{y\bigm|(x,y)\in A\bigr\}=\min_{x\in{\mathbb R}}\left(\min_{y\geq f(x)} y\right)=\min_{x\in{\mathbb R}}f(x)\ .$$